# Fake android library for TDD

Tags: java, android, mocking, tdd

In order to use TDD when developing an android library which can be used in other apps, I decided I could get around the Stub! android.jar by creating copies of the classes which have higher precedence on the classpath (easy using maven, just put it higher in the list of dependencies and mark it as optional).  For example MyService will in my project extend my Fake implementation of android.app.Service and I can mock the Service methods accordingly.

Is there anything really wrong with this approach?  I haven't found such a fake library so I imagine there must be a reason why?

I just want to find out if I am going down the wrong path before I start fleshing out this library and writing more tests?

Answer (score 1):

[Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/) will do most things.

Comment: That's pretty much what I've been looking for except that it seems to be designed for integration style tests rather than unit tests.  I'll give it a try and I'm pretty confident I'll start using it.  Thanks (although I'd still like to hear about unit testing Services and Activities).